# How to convert python arrays to MATLAB readable arrays?

Tags: python, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a function in MATLAB which takes four inputs

```
function f = calculate_mat(F,M,a,b).
```

Here F and M are multi dimensional arrays and 'a' and 'b' are constant terms.

Now I have to call this function in python script where I give all the above input values.

```
import matlab.engine
import numpy as np 

# c, a, b are constants
c = 100 
a = 30 
b = 0.2
freal = np.arange(0,30000,10) # real frequency range
fimag = np.arange(0,200,1) # imaginary frequency range 
F = np.zeros((3000,200))
M = np.zeros((3000,200))
for i in range(len(freal)):
    for j in range(len(fimag)):
        F = freal[i] + fimag[j]
        omega = 2 * np.pi * F[i][j]
        kx = omega / c # wave number 
        M[i][j] = np.abs(kx)

eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
fst = eng.calculate_mat(F, M, a,b)
```

But the python script throws an error : "TypeError: unsupported Python data type: numpy.ndarray"

I have understood that this is because Matlab cannot read in numpy array format.

How to convert numpy array into matlab- readable arrays? Any examples would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] containing `F`, `M`, `a` and `b`

Comment: Have you read https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html?

Comment: @ThomasSablik. Yes, and I used the matlab.double function.                                `F1 = matlab.double([F], is_complex = True)`.                                                                                    But I am getting the following error: " ValueError: initializer must be a rectangular nested sequence "

Comment: You should have given us the information earlier. `[F]` is a list of numpy arrays. You can't initialize a matlab matrix with a list of objects. You have to use the values `F.tolist()`. Next time please post a complete question with all information and the verbatim error messages.

Comment: @ThomasSablik. 'F' is an array. Why do you think it is a list of array? Please correct me, where I am wrong in the code. If you are saying on basis of my comment, then "[F]" this was written from what I understood from the documentation.

Comment: `F` is an array and `[F]` is a list of arrays with one element. You can't neither pass a numpy array nor a list of numpy arrays. You have to convert the numpy array to a basic python list (e.g. with `tolist()`).

Comment: It's difficult to help here because there is a code in the question and a different code in your comment. It's unclear for me how the actual code looks like.

Comment: Okay, I will try to convert to list and try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a matlab function with numpy arrays. You have to convert the numpy arrays to matlab matrices:

```
fst = eng.calculate_mat(matlab.double(F.tolist(), is_complex=True), matlab.double(M.tolist(), is_complex=True), a, b)
```